# Move thumbnail bar in QLPreviewController

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, ios10, quicklook, qlpreviewcontroller

I'm using `QLPreviewController` in my Xamarin application to display PDF files:

```
_qlPreviewController = new QLPreviewController();
_qlPreviewController.DataSource = _dataSource;

_qlPreviewController.View.Frame = _controller.View.Frame;
_controller.View.AddSubview(_qlPreviewController.View);
_qlPreviewController.DidMoveToParentViewController(_controller);
```

This code works pretty good. But since iOS10 it also displays a thumbnail bar on iPad on the right side which covers a little part of a PDF document. This bar cannot be hidden by tap or swipe:
[image]

My question is how can I add a right margin to pages or hide the thumbnail bar programmatically? Is it possible to move this thumbnail bar to another side (e.g. bottom)?

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this?

Comment: @EugeneProkoshev I used the pure UIWebView, it works in the same way as QLPreviewController, but without that sidebar.

Comment: Thanks. I end up using same solution.